# Print list without space in i python-notebook

Tags: python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

```
a="alizafar"

b=len(a)

lis=[1]*b

d=b

sep=""

c=0

while b>0:

    lis[c]=a[c]

    c=c+1

    b=b-1

c=0

while d>0:

    new=lis[c]

    print new,

    c=c+1

    d=d-1
```

result: a l i z a f a r

while I want to print: alizafar

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sys.stdout.write` instead of `print`

```
import sys
a="alizafar"

b=len(a)

lis=[1]*b

d=b

sep=""

c=0

while b>0:

    lis[c]=a[c]

    c=c+1

    b=b-1

c=0

while d>0:

    new=lis[c]

    sys.stdout.write(new)

    c=c+1

    d=d-1
```

will print out

```
alizafar
```